# Selecting a previously clicked element

Tags: jquery, select, click

I need help to select previously clicked element.. (I couldn't find answer) My function is as follows:

```
showSticker:function(){
    $(".Sticker").click(    
        function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass("StickerShow"))
                $(this).removeClass('StickerShow')
            else {
                $(".Sticker").removeClass('StickerShow'); // Here is a problem
                $(this).addClass('StickerShow');
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Actually it works good but I found it pretty dummy to remove class from all matched elements and I noticed that it's pretty hard for CPU to render it.

Comment: This is the simplest, usual, and shouldn't be so slow.

Comment: at least set `var $this=$(this)` and use $this in the code;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems you want like this:

```
showSticker:function(){
    var Stickers=$(".Sticker");
    var lastSticker=Stickers.first();
    Stickers.click(    
        function () {
            $this=$(this);
            if ($this.hasClass("StickerShow"))
                $this.removeClass('StickerShow')
            else {
            // Not worry about removeClass from element which has no such class
                lastSticker.removeClass('StickerShow');
                $this.addClass('StickerShow');
                lastSticker=$this;
            }

        }
    );
}
```

if stickers are siblings you can use simple  `$this.siblings('.StickerShow').removeClass('StickerShow')` and `$this.toggleClass('StickerShow')` instead of `if/else`

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes exactly like this. You have missed last bracket and one letter here: var lastSticker=Sticker<s>.first();

Answer (score 0):

You could cache a few things and not traverse the DOM unnecessarily:

```
var $stickers = $('.Sticker');

// ...

showSticker: function() {
    $stickers.click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        if ($this.hasClass("StickerShow")) {
            $this.removeClass('StickerShow')
        } else {
            $stickers.removeClass('StickerShow'); // Here is a problem
            $this.addClass('StickerShow');
        }
    });
}
```